# 2D array won't print properly

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to program a dungeon crawl game and the compiler won't print out my grid properly, for some reason it only prints out the first element in each row without giving me any error messages.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

char myGrid[7][10]{{'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
                   {'.', '.', 'P', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'T', '.', '.'},
                   {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
                   {'.', '.', '.', '.', 'T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
                   {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'T', '.', '.', '.'},
                   {'.', '.', 'T', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
                   {'.', '.', '.', '.', 'X', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}};

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        cout << myGrid[i][j] << " ";
        if(j = 9){
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the output I get from my console:

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

Comment: You probably meant `if(j == 9)`

Comment: pay attention to compiler warnings !

Comment: Using `if(9 == j)` let's the compiler catch your problem, when you mistype `if(9 = j)`.  Top tip?  Some folk think it looks weird,  but I like it!

Comment: Not doing the check helps even more. `endl` can be printed easily outside the inner loop, thus avoiding the comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the line: `if(j = 9)`. You need a double equals to compare. Here, you're assigning to `j`, which makes it skip the rest of the line.

Unsolicited advice:

1. Avoid hard-coding your constants (e.g., 7, 10, 9). Use `sizeof` for arrays, or at least a constant value like `const auto rows = 7;`.
2. If you get much more complex or bigger maps, you should probably move away from raw arrays to `std::vector` or perhaps `std::array`. If you do this, you can solve #1 by using `myGrid.size()` and `myGrid[row].size()`.
3. [Use `'\n'` rather than `std::endl`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMqQOEZYVJQ).

Comment: @Yami: I mean that repeating constant values such as the size of the rows and columns throughout the code is a recipe for bugs and unmaintainability. Adding names to constants helps readability and maintainability, e.g., if you change the number of rows or columns later and then forget to change one place. Moreover, 9 is a dependent constant in that it is the `number of columns - 1`. You should state that via a mathematical expression rather than making it a bare 9 with not obvious connection to the number of columns. As for `std::endl`, see the hyperlinked video for details on why.